# Which Refer will be send in this example? (Webbrowser Html)

Tags: html, iframe

Lets assume i have a page with a iframe. The page is www.something.de and the iframe contains another page.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" style="border: 0; width: 250px; height: 250px;"src="//otherurl.com/something.php"></iframe>
<a href="//www.thirdpage.de" target="_blank" class="headline">A</a>
```

the iframed page has a Link to a third page.
If a user clicks on the iframes link (third page) what referer will be send by the browser? The Main page (something.de) or the iframed page containing the link?

Would be great if someone could answer this. If you need more informations about my question please ask.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try it: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6herzkm/1/). As jsfiddle includes the user-defined content in an iframe, the link I added is within an iframe whose URL differs from the URL of the fiddle itself. As you can see when you click the link, the referer is the iframe URL, not the iframe's parent URL.

The URL of the iframe will be sent as the `Referer`. This makes sense to ensure integrity of the included page.

And to quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) (emphasis added):

> In the most common situation this means that when a user clicks a
> hyperlink in a web browser, the browser sends a request to the server
> holding the destination webpage. The request includes the referrer
> field, which indicates the last page the user was on **(the one where
> they clicked the link)**.

[RFC 7231 states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2) (emphasis added):

> The "Referer" [sic] header field allows the user agent to specify a
> URI **reference for the resource from which the target URI was obtained** [...].

Comment: @MaioSteger Please accept the answer to mark this question as answered.